# How to prevent cheating in frontend React game

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I've made a typing speed game and would like to make a backend for it to save user high scores, then make a leaderboard. How would I prevent someone from faking their highscore? [Image of game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWfGR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not easy. The best answer to stopping fake highscore submissions is to require an audit trail: continual submission of game progress ie how the high score was achieved. Even if someone creates a way to defeat this check, you can run statistical analysis to analyze their game.

The other way I can think of is a Chrome extension, something like this one with surviv.io

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/anti-cheat-extension-for/lfhgglhliclgicjndggiedneblgemjgl